# ReadAsAsync Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I have run into a problem with using ReadAsAsync to deserialize as list of objects from JSON being returned from a web service. The resulting list has the correct number of records, but all the properties on the objects are null. The strange thing is that the same code works fine for my co-workers, and the code works ok for me in other solutions. I distilled the code down to this:

```
  var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(@"{""Currency"": ""USD""}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var prices = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Price>().Result;

  public class Price
    {
        public string Currency { get; set; }
    }
```

This will execute fine, but the Currency property will be null. I tried copying this code to a blank ASP.NET MVC solution and it worked fine. I also tried it in both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 and had the same problem in both.

Comment: "I tried copying this code to a blank ASP.NET MVC solution and it worked fine". Please post a [mcve] of that. How you defined the `Price` class is most likely the problem

Comment: and you should almost never do Async().Result

Comment: I have added the price class, although that wouldn't be the problem since the code works fine for other developers on my team.

Comment: `ReadAsAsync<>` is from  `Assembly: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`, do you have right package installed?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to this problem. It had to do with the NewtonSoft.Json assembly. It appears there was a version conflict between the one in the GAC and the one used by Visual Studio. Replacing the one in the GAC with the one from Visual Studio resolved the issue. Here is the article I found with this solution.

https://billti.github.io/jsdocs/articles/troubleshooting/newtonsoft.html